# APNs-sharp libraries not working on windows server 2008, CryptographicException

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-server-2008-r2, apns-sharp

I have an asp.net application that uses the [APNs-Sharp](https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp) libraries to send push notifications.  It works fine on my local machine but when i publish to a windows 2008 r2 server machine I get the following error:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password)
   at JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications.NotificationConnection.start(String p12File, String p12FilePassword)
   at JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications.NotificationService.set_Connections(Int32 value)
   at JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications.NotificationService..ctor(Boolean sandbox, String p12File, String p12FilePassword, Int32 connections)
```

I'm not sure why its getting this error only the on the server machine.. Does anyone have any ideas on what the problem could be?

I added a check to my code to see that the certificate file can be found on the server and it is. the password is correct. So the only thing i left i can think of is that it has something to do with with windows server 2008 r2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution. in iis management console you have to set the default application pools identity to local system.

Comment: Thanks. It is working. But can you please explain what was the issue when I used Application pools identity?